# How I could save data using realm in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift

I have table where I can add some empty cells. Using protocol I can send some data to each cell. When I am looking into the table I can see all the information I sent. My problem happens when try to save date using realm, only save last sent data to cell.

// model:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

    class HITActionModel: Object {
        @objc dynamic var seconds: Int = 0
        @objc dynamic var color: String = ""
        @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
        @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
        var parentWorkout = LinkingObjects(fromType: WorkoutModel.self, property: "actionsArray")
    }

    class WorkoutModel: Object {
        @objc dynamic var title: String?
        @objc dynamic var rounds: Int = 0
        var actionsArray = List<HITActionModel>()
    }
```

//protocol

```
protocol HITActionCellDelegate {
        func action(sec: Int, name: String, id: Int)
    }
```

//custom cell

```
 class HITActionCell: UITableViewCell {

        //MARK: - Properties

        @IBOutlet weak var changeColorBtn: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var actionLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var actionNameTextField: UITextField!

        var delegate: HITActionCellDelegate?
        var numberOfSeconds = 0
        var id = 0

        //MARK: - Lifecycle

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            selectionStyle = .none
        }

        //MARK: - Elements setup

        func setupElements() {
            actionNameTextField.placeholder = "Add name for Action!"
            changeColorBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.neonYellow
            actionLabel.text = "Entry seconds for action"
        }

        @IBAction func addActionSeconds(_ sender: Any) {
            numberOfSeconds += 1
            actionLabel.text = "\(numberOfSeconds) SECONDS"
            delegate?.action(sec: numberOfSeconds, name: actionNameTextField.text ?? "", id: self.id)
        }

        @IBAction func reduceActionSeconds(_ sender: Any) {
            if numberOfSeconds > 0 {
                numberOfSeconds -= 1
                actionLabel.text = "\(numberOfSeconds) SECONDS"
                delegate?.action(sec: numberOfSeconds, name: actionNameTextField.text ?? "", id: self.id)
            }
        }
    }
```

//  From here I send data using Protocol to viewController :

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class AddActionViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Properties

    let workout = WorkoutModel()
    let action = HITActionModel()

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var numberOfRounds = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var workoutNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var roundsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addRounds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var reduceRounds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addActionButton: UIButton!

    //MARK:- Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupUI()            
        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: Const.UI.NibName.hiActionCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: Const.UI.CellIdentifier.hiActionCell)
    }

    //MARK:- Elements setup

    func setupUI() {

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        title = Const.NameString.workouts
        addActionButton.setTitle(Const.NameString.addAction, for: .normal)
        addActionButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
        addActionButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.textStyle9

        workoutNameLabel.text = Const.NameString.workoutName
        workoutNameLabel.font = UIFont.textStyle7
        workoutNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

        workoutNameTextField.textColor = UIColor.black
        workoutNameTextField.font = UIFont.textStyle8

        roundsLabel.text = Const.NameString.startingRounds
        roundsLabel.font = UIFont.textStyle9
        roundsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        roundsLabel.textAlignment = .center
    }


    @IBAction func saveButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if workoutNameTextField.text != "" {
            workout.title = workoutNameTextField.text!
            workout.rounds = numberOfRounds

            save(workout)

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let myalert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: "You forgot something to add ;) (name, rounds, seconds)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            myalert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "I'm guilty", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(myalert, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func save(_ workout: WorkoutModel) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(workout)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    @IBAction func addActionButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        workout.actionsArray.append(action)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: workout.actionsArray.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    @IBAction func addRoundsBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        numberOfRounds += 1
        roundsLabel.text = "\(numberOfRounds) ROUNDS"
    }

    @IBAction func reduceRoundsBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if numberOfRounds > 0 {
            numberOfRounds -= 1
            roundsLabel.text = "\(numberOfRounds) ROUNDS"
        }
    }
}

//MARK:- Setup TextFieldDelegate Method

extension AddActionViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        workoutNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}

//Quick guide implementation for showing and deleting cells

extension AddActionViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workout.actionsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Const.UI.CellIdentifier.hiActionCell) as? HITActionCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.setupElements()
        cell.id = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            workout.actionsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        if (editingStyle == .insert) {
            print("test")
        }
    }
extension AddActionViewController: HITActionCellDelegate {

    func action(sec: Int, name: String, id: Int) {
        action.name = name
        action.seconds = sec
        action.id = id
    }
}
```

If could someone help me, It would be greet for me :)

Comment: Now I have put it my model. My problem happens when use addActionButtonPressed where adding new action (cells) and then using protocol I send data to that cells, but when I try to save it using realm, I only save the data in last cell.  Sorry because mine poor explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remove func saveAction(_ action: HITActionModel). This is something I try, but I didn

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remove func saveAction(_ action: HITActionModel). This is something I try, but I didn't get result. I try to explain on different ways: On my View Controller I have two fields, where I can add name and some numbers and there is no problem saving that data using realm, but I also have tableview where I can add more custom cells (its my actions). I have to tie up data in tableview with data in two fields I mention before. I don't now how to explain better. Thanks in advance.